# Linearisation of the IS curve?

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics, monetary-policy, self-study

[image]

How to the IS curve linearised around the structural equilibrium?, what is the math behind it?

Comment: Perhaps the notation would make more sense to some of us if you could share the name of the source?

Comment: Can u add the source/more info please?